# how do I find and install a root ssl certificate on debian?

Tags: nginx, ssl, debian, ssl-certificate

I am running nginx on debian 10.

I installed a cert and checked with https://www.sslchecker.com/

The cert itself and chain certs1&2 check out but the root is missing.

I downloaded the root cert from sslchecker and installed by copying it to  /etc/ca-certificates/ and running  update-ca-certificates. The command seems fine but I still get a missing root error from sslchecker.

Perhaps another root cert or install procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nginx you have to concatenate everything into a single bundle of chained certificates, see [SSL certificate chains](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains).

Comment: I got a complete ca from the vendor.  Thank you